# C++ How do I create class members within other classes?

Tags: c++, class, syntax

When I'm trying to create a class member in the private section of a class I get "expected a type specifier". Why does it error like this in the private section of WordCount Class but is fine inside main()?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct AVLNode
{
    T element; //later might want to make this a T
    AVLNode* left;
    AVLNode* right;
    int height;

    //Constructor:
    AVLNode(T theElement, AVLNode<T>* lt, AVLNode<T>* rt, int ht = 0) //ht is short for height
        : element(theElement), left(lt), right(rt), height(ht) {}
};

template <class T>
class AVLTree
{
protected:
    AVLNode<T>* root = NULL;
    const T ITEM_NOT_FOUND;

public:
    AVLTree<T>(T notFound)
        : ITEM_NOT_FOUND(notFound), root(NULL) {}
};

class WordCount
{
private:
    AVLTree<int> tree(0); //Error
};

int main()
{
    AVLTree<int> avl(0);
}
```

Comment: Bit of a weird spot, this. Hopefully someone will come by with a language rule explain why this doesn't work, but to get around it you can `AVLTree<int> tree = AVLTree<int>(0);` If the argument is not a compile time constant, you'll have to use a `WordCount` constructor. `WordCount(int arg): tree(arg) {}`

Comment: How would you implement that constructor? I tried putting it inside the public section of WordCount but I'm having no luck with the error.

Comment: You need to use `{}` for initialization in class-scope. `AVLTree<int> tree{0};`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a life-saver!

Comment: @Art my apologies for leaving out important information. If you go the constructor route, `AVLTree<int> tree(0);` is still an error and would have to be changed to `AVLTree<int> tree;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use brace instead of parantheses for member [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members):

> Non-static data members may be initialized in one of two ways:...
>   Through a default member initializer, **which is simply a *brace* or
>   equals initializer included in the member declaration,** which is used
>   if the member is omitted in the member initializer list

You can try parantheses with `int` and see it doesn't work for `int` too.

Comment: Do you know why this is the case? Most vexing parse comes to mind, but it seems it's not an exact fit in this case. Is it just to simplify the parsing rules since there are some cases where it can be ambiguous?

Comment: @super my wild guess is to prevent implicit conversion.